# How to add row below the sum of row's values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is the example for my table. I need to add a row below the sum of no of phones for month with respect to city by writing a stored procedure in SQL Server. Thanks in advance.

```
country  city         store      phonetype   phonename    month(no.of phones)
---------------------------------------------------------------
 India   bangalore   reliance    android      oneplus      22
 India   bangalore   reliance    android      vivo        167
 India   bangalore   reliance    android      redmi       106
 India   Hyderabad   BigC        android      oppo        223
 India   Hyderabad   BigC        android      vivo         55
```

Comment: It will be very helpful to solve your problem, if you provide a sample output Table. Best Wishes :-)

Comment: Rows in a table have no particular order. It is only when you select those rows that they **can** be ordered. So are you trying to add total rows to a resultset or do you actually want to insert those rows into your table?

Comment: for example,i have to get total phone(no of phones) for bangalore city.total count shou;ld be add below total.thanq

Comment: You have to call another `select` statement and sum the values you want, and then call `union` to show both result as a unique table.

Comment: can show me the query for this .it woulfd be helpful .thnq

Comment: @Hamed_gibago No, you can use `GROUPING SETS` or `ROLLUP` to achieve the same more efficiently

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `GROUPING SETS` for this

```sql
SELECT
  t.country,
  t.city,
  t.store,
  t.phonetype,
  t.phonename,
  CASE WHEN GROUPING(t.store) = 1 THEN 'SubTotal' END RowType,
  SUM(t.[month(no.of phones)]) AS [month(no.of phones)]
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
    (t.country, t.city, t.store, t.phonetype, t.phonename, t.[month(no.of phones)]),
    (t.country, t.city)
)
ORDER BY
  t.country,
  t.city,
  GROUPING(t.store);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bfb4edec614956b89856d74d47915a77)